# Call php-cgi.exe from a Windows service written in c++

Tags: php, c++, windows, service

I have a c++ application that uses php-cgi to run some php scripts.  I specifically need to use php-cgi because the scripts require parameters to be passed in.  When running as a Windows service, I am unable to get these scripts to respond with any data.

The specific code that I'm having trouble with, is very simple, as follows:

```
    FILE* hFilePipe{ _popen( strPhpCommand.c_str(), "rb" ) };
    if ( hFilePipe != nullptr ) {...
```

This code works fine as a stand alone app, and on Linux.  When running as a service, everything SEEMS fine.  The file handle is opened ok, but there is no data to read from the pipe.  I've added some file output into the php script to see if it's actually running, and the results of that are blank, so it seems that the script doesn't get run at all, even though there's no error from _popen and I'm able to happily receive the zero bytes that are waiting for me.

Scouring the web for answers, all I've been able to ascertain is that executing applications from a service seems to be something that isn't allowed due to some kind of OS security layers getting in the way.

So in summary, how can I get my c++ Windows service to run a php script and get its results?

Comment: Does the account the windows service runs under have sufficient permissions to access and execute the PHP script?

Comment: It's running as 'Local System'.  What do I need to check to see whether that has permissions?  I would have thought the _popen command would result in an error if it didn't have permissions though.  The result of _popen is a valid file handle.